# Magento 2.1: add attribute to select on product repository

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

Using the product repository and having product sku, would be possible to retrieve only 1 product attribute by code?

I tried `getCustomAttribute('code')` but using **Xdebug** still I can see all attributes before the function, so it seems to be not effective.

I wonder if there is any difference, in terms of performances, using getAttributeCode() or getCustomAttribute()